# How to see what words a person has inputed in Python?

Tags: python, input

So I've been trying to make a calculator as a school project, but I can't seem to read a person's input when I ask them for multiplication or addition. It goes something like this:

```
num1=input("Enter first number.")
num2=input("Enter second number.")

mora=input("Multiplication or addition please.")

sum1 = num1 + num2

if('Addition' in mora)print (sum1)
```

How can I print sum1 when someone types addition?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   What happens when you run your code?

Comment: it is because you are using 'addition' in input method, but you are trying to search for 'Addition', you can add like this if ('Addition'.lower() in mora.lower())

Comment: Why calculate the sum before checking what's been entered?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is execute a proper `if` statement

```
if mora.lower() == 'addition':
    print(sum1)
```

Comment: The question already has an if statement

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes but he had it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not valid, you need a colon:

```
if 'Addition' in mora:
    print(sum1)
```

But also, your inputs are strings, so you're concatenating the numbers-as-strings rather than adding the numbers.

```
num1 = int(input("Enter first number."))
# or float, if you're allowing floats
```

Comment: And of course, they're not checking case insensitive.

Comment: That too! Building your first calculator program really is a learning experience, they will probably run into many more issues.

Answer (score 0):

You were doing everything right but your syntax is wrong, the if statement should be like

```
if condition:
    your code here
```

Implementing this to your code and it will be like

```
if 'Addition' in mora:
    print(sum1)
```